# Can one use OpenGL in the Kernel?

Tags: linux, opengl, kernel, driver

Can I use OpenGL in the Linux Kernel? That is, I'd like to improve the performance of some code, so using the GPU would be benefit for another driver. It's certain the GPU would be fixed on the machine for which this kernel would be build.

Sorry if I sound naive, I am just trying to get the general picture for the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, the biggest reason is that you can't use floating point math in the kernel. Besides that accessing such driver from within the kernel is a very bad idea. I don't know if the kernel is even able to link to a usermode library (libGL.so or libOpenCL.so).

Comment: It is possible to use the FPU in kernel mode, but it's incredibly difficult and tedious. And usually it shouldn't be neccesary. Unfortunately I had to deal with some device recently, which required me to do floating point operations in the kernel module *gah*.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am still wondering though whether it's possible to load the opengl library from within the kernel. :-)

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore: No it is not possible. User space libraries expect a completely different environment, than what can be found in the kernel.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL is for displaying 3D on screen, I really don't know in which way you want to use it in the kernel.

If you meant using the computational power of the GPU for some calculations, I think it would be feasible in some parts of the kernel, but I doubt it is worth the pain.

Comment: I am thinking of doing some GPGPU programming, i.e. stream processing.

Comment: @Albus Dumbeldore: And why do this in the kernel? One wants to spend as few time in kernel mode as possible.

Comment: Um, yes, but as far as I understand it correctly, it is going to be a part of a device driver I'll need to modify a bit.

Comment: @Albus Dumbleore: A GPU device driver, or something entirely different?

Comment: A display driver for some peculiar type of displays

Answer (score 3):

- GPUs simply don't work the way you imagine.
- What do you want to accelerate? Just some standard computation? Kernel code does not run faster than user space code! Actually some things are even slower.
- You know, that even using the floating point unit (FPU) in the kernel is highly nontrivial and discouraged.
- GPU computing is not a magic bullet.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice! What I am trying to achieve is implement some code that would be more efficient if implemented using the stream processing paradigm.

Comment: So what shall this thing do? Which kind of hardware is that driver for. What kind of data.

Comment: I am only interested in whether it's possible and feasible to invoke OpenGL from within the Kernel.

Comment: In one word: No! All the existing OpenGL implementations live entirely in the userspace. Actually all Linux graphics drivers live there, too. DRI/DRM is just a very thin layer for accessing elementary graphics hardware functions through a unified kernel interface. But so far all higher level functions of current graphic drivers are in user space. This includes OpenGL. However, given enough time, resources and work it would be possible to move OpenGL entirely into the kernel. But nobody would do this as the kernel is just not the right place where to implement these things.